# Black Screen of Death in Mobile

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to figure out in my customer's Mobile what causes black screens of death. The apk in different places and random moments causes a black screen of death and application stucks. I have place exceptions almost everywhere but i dont get any exception message.I will send you an examample from my code:
What can cause this black screens???

Here is my class:

```
class MyListViewAdapterInventory : BaseAdapter<InventoryPreviewClass>
{
    public List<InventoryPreviewClass> mitems;
    private Context mContext;
    private int mRowLayout;
    private int[] mAlternatingColors;


    public MyListViewAdapterInventory(Context context, int rowLayout, List<InventoryPreviewClass> items)
    {
        mitems = items;
        mContext = context;
        mRowLayout = rowLayout;
        mAlternatingColors = new int[] { 0xF2F2F2, 0xbfddff };

    }
    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return mitems.Count;
        }
    }
    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public override InventoryPreviewClass this[int position]
    {
        get
        {
            return mitems[position];
        }

    }
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {



        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null)
        {
            row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.InventoryPreview, null, false);

        }


         row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.InventoryPreview, null, false);
            row.SetBackgroundColor(GetColorFromInteger(mAlternatingColors[position % mAlternatingColors.Length]));
        TextView txtInventoryID = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtInventoryID);
            txtInventoryID.Text = mitems[position].InventoryItemID;
        TextView txtInventoryName = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtInventoryName);
            txtInventoryName.Text = mitems[position].InventoryItemName;
        TextView txtInventoryPrice = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtInventoryPrice);
            txtInventoryPrice.Text = mitems[position].InventoryItemPrice.Replace(",", ".");
        Button ExtraBtn = row.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ExtrasBtn);

            ExtraBtn.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Connection.InventoryItemID = mitems[position].InventoryItemID;
                    Connection.InventoryItemName = mitems[position].InventoryItemName;
                    Connection.RetailPrice = mitems[position].InventoryItemPrice;
                    Toast toast = Toast.MakeText(mContext, txtInventoryName.Text, ToastLength.Short);
                    toast.Show();
                    mContext.StartActivity(typeof(ExtrasPreviewMain));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Toast toast = Toast.MakeText(mContext, Convert.ToString(ex), ToastLength.Long);
                    toast.Show();
                }

            };




        return row;

    }
    private Color GetColorFromInteger(int color)
    {
        return Color.Rgb(Color.GetRedComponent(color), Color.GetGreenComponent(color), Color.GetBlueComponent(color));
    }
}
```

And here is my activity Main when running:

```
private List<InventoryPreviewClass> mItems;
private ListView mlistview;
private EditText mSearch;
private EditText etSearchAlwaysOn;
private LinearLayout mContainer;
private bool mAnimatedDown;
private bool mIsAnimating;
private MyListViewAdapterInventory mAdapter;
string dpPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "student.db3");
SQLiteConnection db;
private TextView mTxtHeaderFirstName;
private TextView mTxtHeaderLastName;

private bool mFirstNameAscending;
private bool mLastNameAscending;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    try
    {
        ActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.InventoryPreviewMain);
        OverridePendingTransition(Resource.Layout.trans_left_in, Resource.Layout.trans_left_out);

        mSearch = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.etSearch);
        etSearchAlwaysOn = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.etSearchAlwaysOn);
        mContainer = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.llContainer);

        mTxtHeaderFirstName = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtHeaderFirstName);
        mTxtHeaderLastName = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtHeaderLastName);

        mTxtHeaderFirstName.Click += mTxtHeaderFirstName_Click;
        mTxtHeaderLastName.Click += mTxtHeaderLastName_Click;

        mSearch.Alpha = 0;
        mContainer.BringToFront();

        mSearch.TextChanged += mSearch_TextChanged;
        etSearchAlwaysOn.TextChanged += EtSearchAlwaysOn_TextChanged;

        mlistview = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.InventoryList);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, Convert.ToString(ex), ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
    try
    {
        db = new SQLiteConnection(dpPath);
        var table = db.Query<InventoryPreviewClass>("select * from InventoryPreviewClass where CategoryID =" + Connection.CategoryID+ "");
        mItems = new List<InventoryPreviewClass>();
        foreach (var item in table)
        {
            mItems.Add(new InventoryPreviewClass() { InventoryItemID = item.InventoryItemID, InventoryItemName = item.InventoryItemName, InventoryItemPrice = item.InventoryItemPrice });
        }
            MyListViewAdapterInventory adapter = new MyListViewAdapterInventory(this, Resource.Layout.InventoryPreview, mItems);
            mlistview.Adapter = adapter;
            mlistview.ItemClick += Mlistview_ItemClick;
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    try
    {
        if (SearchAlwaysOn == true)
        {
            var param = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)etSearchAlwaysOn.LayoutParameters;
            var WidthParam = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent;
            var HeigthParam = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent;
            param.Width = WidthParam;
            param.Height = HeigthParam;
            mIsAnimating = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, Convert.ToString(ex), ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried using a crash reporting service like HockeyApp or App Center?

Comment: No i dont know what is this app.Do i need rooting?

Comment: no - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/crashes/

Comment: Is it possible the animated whay which i'm changing screen to cause this Problem? OverridePendingTransition(Resource.Layout.trans_left_in, Resource.Layout.trans_left_out);

Comment: #1 question: can the problem be reproduced?  Then: 2) if so, can you reproduce it in your dev environment?  3) Does your application do logging?  4) If not, why not?  5) If yes, then do the logs show any warnings or errors?  More importantly, where do the logs "stop"?

Comment: Q: "Is it possible the animated whay which i'm changing screen to cause this Problem?"  A: DON'T GUESS!!!!!  Try to reproduce the problem, try to get some facts about the problem!  BTW: AppCenter is an *excellent* suggestion.  Try it!

Comment: 1)No. The apk crashes in random time,in random place.2) No i cannt reproduce it in my dev enviroment. In my dev enviroment everything goes perfet without any crash one year now. 3) My application making logging but the problem is not captured it is like something is no be cathed as exception. What doy you mean where logs stop?

Comment: could it be related to LayoutInflater that you've called twice in the adapter?

Comment: Maybe... But if i will noy use this when opening another activity and pressing back button it reopens existing activity and no previous one

Comment: @Dss - have you resolved the problem?  Or learned anything more about "what's different" between your customer and your dev environment?  Or built an "instrumented .apk" for your customer with additional logging (it can help answer "what's the last thing that happened before the crash?")

Comment: No unforunately i didnt resolve 100% my problem. There are days that works ok and day which has black screens. Someone told me to check about ui thread.But the database which i run on create doesnt have more than 100 rows.I'm in search.I am glad to hear for any help!